# Game is repeated twice and SPNE

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I am currently learning about SPNE in repeated game, and I came across this problem with the following payoff table (denote columns as A,B,C and rows as D E F.)

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
(-9, -9) & (0, -10) & (-15,-10) \\
\hline
(-10,0) & (-1,-1) & (-15,-10) \\
\hline
(-10,-15) & (-10,-15) & (-12,-12)\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Suppose this game is repeated twice. Player 1 stands for row. Player 2 stands for column.

**Question** Can (B,E) be supported in the first round? If it is, what is the discount factor?

**My attempt**

The answer is **YES.** My reasoning is following: $(B,E)$ is played in the first time, play $(A,D)$ in the second time, which is a Nash equilibrium of the stage game (the other equilibrium is $(C,F)$), the total payoff in period 1 for player 1 (and player 2 as well, due to symmetry in the payoff values) $= -1 -9\delta$. We can show that this is the highest payoff player 1 can obtain:

Playing $(A,D)$ twice or $(C,F)$ twice, or any mixed strategy between them, results in $-9-9\delta$ and $-12-12\delta$, and $[-9x - 12(1-x)](1+\delta)$ for $x\in (0,1)$. But all of these payoffs are less than $-1-9\delta$. So the strategy profile of playing (B,E) in the 1st period, and then (C,F) in the 2nd period, is a SPNE(?!).

At this point, I don't see why we need certain conditions on the discount factors (because the game is only repeated **twice**, not infinite), except maybe trying to bound the payoff of $-1 -9\delta$ between min-max payoff and max-min payoff?

Can someone please help review my solution above? I find the conclusion weird, but I am not sure what went wrong. Note that strategy F dominates strategy E, so we can get rid of F (but then $(B,E)$ would not exist anymore).

Comment: "strategy $D$ dominates strategy $E$, so we can get rid of $F$" – I think you mean $E$?

Comment: @joriki Yes! I fixed it. Thank you. Can you give it a try?

Comment: To avoid false impressions: I didn't write an answer because of the request in your last comment (to the contrary, I'm annoyed by such requests in response to constructive comments); I was already writing it at that time.

Comment: @joriki My apology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re comparing the payoff to a payoff that results if both players switch strategies. A (subgame-perfect) Nash equilibrium is defined by each player’s strategy being the best response to the *fixed* strategies of the other players. So you need to compare the putative equilibrium strategy profile to strategy profiles where player $1$ chooses a different strategy while player $2$ sticks to her strategy.

You haven’t specified a full strategy profile; you only wrote how the players act in the first round, and how they act in the second round given those actions in the first round – but a strategy profile also includes how they act in the second round if the other player acts differently in the first round. In the present case, it’s part of the subgame-perfect Nash equilibrium that both players threaten to play $C/F$ if the result of the first round is not $(B,E)$. They can do this because both $(B,E)$ and $(C,F)$ are Nash equilibria in the non-repeated game.

If player $1$ deviates from this putative equilibrium strategy profile and plays $A$ in the first round, both players will play $F$ in the second round. The resulting discounted payoff for player $1$ is $0-12\delta$. Comparing this to $-1-9\delta$ yields the desired bound on the discount factor.

By the way, the game is solved in [these slides](https://sites.duke.edu/niou/files/2011/05/Lecture-5-Repeated-Games.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! However, isn't it the case that if player 1 plays $A$, then player 2 plays $A$ as well in the first case? So the discounted payoff should be $-9-12\delta$, which requires $\delta > 1$ (unreasonable). I'm not sure what motivates player 2 to plays $E$ when player 1 plays $A$ (with that said, why doesn't player 2 plays $F$ when player 1 plays $A$? Doesn't it mean we have to test *all* cases that are off equilibrium??). But I can see that it is an off-equilibrium path for player 2.

Comment: @ghjk: That's not how a (subgame-perfect) Nash equilibrium works. The players' strategies are varied only individually. When we vary player $1$'s strategy we only compare the expected payoff for player $1$ for different strategies for player $1$; the strategy of player $2$ is fixed, and we don't ask what might motivate her to follow that strategy. The strategy profile is in equilibrium if neither player profits by unilaterally deviating from it, i.e. both players are motivated to stick to it. That doesn't mean that they might not be motivated to deviate if the other player were to deviate.

Comment: I see what you meant. I have an additional question though: can we bound $-1-9\delta$ from above with the min-max payoff for player 1 in the 2nd period, which is $-10$ in this case? And also from below with the max-min payoff, which is $-12$?

Comment: @ghjk: I don't see why we should be able to (or indeed want to) do that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: What I meant is we need $-1-9\delta$ to be between $-10$ and $-12$. But  this is obviously true, since $\delta \in [0,1]$. Nvm...

Comment: @ghjk: No, that's not true. With $\delta\in[0,1]$, we have $-1\le-1-9\delta\le-10$.

Comment: Well, $-1$>$-12$, so...it's true.And you reverse the signs of the inequality twice.

Comment: @ghjk: I did get the sign of the inequalities wrong, but that doesn't change the fact that the numbers between $-1$ and $-10$ don't lie between $-10$ and $-12$ (though they do lie above $-12$).

Comment: You are right. So I am not sure why some slides said the min-max payoff of player $i$ is the upper bound of player i's payoff then? Also, in the original problem, am I correct that we also need to consider the situation where $(C,D)$ or $(C,E)$ played in the first round to get another lower bounds on $\delta$? This would be equivalent to finding $\delta\in (0,1)$ s.t $-1-9\delta \geq -10-12\delta$, which is always true! Hence, your $(A,E)$ case is sufficient (did you come up with $(A,E)$ by assuming the 2nd player is off-equilibrium path? But we are considering player 1's payoff).

Comment: you wrote that "They can do this because both (,) and (,) are Nash equilibria in the non-repeated game." But $(B,E)$ is NOT a Nash equilibrium for a stage (or reduced) game though.